# Type Mismatch in nested loops with WorksheetFunction

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

```
Sub checkMe()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cell As Range



lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In Range("B1:B" & lastRow) 'dynamically go through each row in the range 
        For a_counter = 2001 To 2015 ' for each row, cycle through each year until 2015 
        j = a_counter
        b = cell.offset(0, 6).Value 'value for vlookup
        a = Application.VLookup(b, Sheet2.Range("A2:N42"), (j - 2000 + 2), False) ' look up each value in offset(0,6) in another sheet 
        If cell.Value = "DUB" And cell.offset(0, 1).Value <= "2001" And cell.offset(0, 2).Value = "OSLR" Then cell.offset(0, j + 12 - 2000).Value = cell.offset(0, 7).Value * a 'only apply when the conditions are met 


        Next a_counter


Next

End Sub
```

The order should be changed up a bit so the conditions are before the inside loop to help speed but otherwise I think this should work. The value of the cell.offset(0,6) is the value I need to look up for each row for the vlookups. This code works if I put in a value where 'b' is, however I need the value to look up to change with each row. Currently it just works for the 1st row and stops. Right now I get a mismatch error.

Comment: Where do you get the `Type Mismatch` error?

Comment: how to i figure out where? it just says Type Mismatch

Comment: There should be a Debug button and when you press that it will highlight the line.

Comment: dont see it on visual basic. I tried everything in the debug tab

Comment: No - when the error occurs, there should be a debug button on the message box that comes up?

Comment: Change lastRow to integer then try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do some math.

```
For a_counter = 2001 To 2015
```

**a_counter** will sequence through 15 values; e.g. 2001 ► 2015 inclusive.

```
Sheet2.Range("A2:N42")
```

Total of 14 columns; e.g. column A ► column N inclusive.

```
j = a_counter
..., (j - 2000 + 2), ...
```

You are asking for returns from 15 different columns from 3 ► 17.

However A:N has 14 columns so you will error out (Type mismatch) when **a_counter** = 2013 because there is no 15<sup>th</sup> column.